# How to upload application to app world step by step?

Tags: blackberry, upload, blackberry-world

I would like to know how to upload application to App World step by step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all here: [BlackBerry App World Distribution](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/distribution.jsp).